# API to trigger series of Python scripts

Tags: python, api, flask

I have 3 python scripts

1. **grab.py:** Takes as input an Instagram account name and outputs a text file containing all of its followers.
2. **scrape.py:** Takes as input the output from grab.py and outputs details of each account (follower count, post count etc) in csv form
3. **analyze.py:** A basic machine learning model that uses results of scrape.py to perform an analysis on the accounts.

The 3 scripts work as expected individually. The next step is to create an API endpoint which will take an account name as a request parameter, and then trigger the above 3 scripts for the received account. The final analysis results will be stored in a database.

The endpoint also needs to have a queueing mechanism to store account names received. The queue will be polled, and if account names are available, they will be processed sequentially.

My API development experience is limited so I am not sure of the best approach to tackle this problem. My questions are:

1. Should my API endpoint be written in Python? If yes, is the Flask framework a viable option? If not, what are the other options I have?
2. Is there some sort of a pipeline that I can use to seamlessly integrate the 3 scripts together?
3. Is the idea of maintaining the queue in memory and polling it using a separate thread running an infinite while loop a good idea? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Although a perfect valid question I fear the possible answers are all opinion-based - which makes it off-topic for this Q&A site (opinion-based answers are frowned upon here because the tend to invite flame-wars and trolling). That said, I use Python all the time for APIs (Django REST Framework) and people tend to use an asynchronous task queue like [Celery](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) to handle this kind of problem. If the tasks are dependent on each other you may be interested in the [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) project.

Comment: 1) IMO flask would be a viable and quick option.

2) No idea

3) Since queues can used in a blocking fashion this seems like an okay idea. One drawback is that it is, as you said, in memory and will be lost once the program ends. You could use a database like sqlite or a file instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get info from an API and save it I would recommend using asyncio to do something like

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
import aiofiles as aiof

FILENAME = "foo.txt"
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        async with aiof.open(FILENAME, "a") as out:
            out.write((await response.json()))
            out.flush()



async def main():
    instagram-ids = [] #profile ids
    current = time.time()
    url = "INSTAGRAM_API_URL"
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for id in instagram-ids:
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(fetch(session, url.format(id))))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(time.time() - current)

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

since most of the time when dealing with API is spent on waiting for the results